# NullReferenceException on DropDownListFor after [HttpPost]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, nullreferenceexception

In my application I'am populating a dropdownlist from database using ADO Entity Framework, after this when i try to submit the form the value of the dropdown list it is giving Null reference exception.

***Error Code (in INDEX.ASPX)***

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.race, Model.Races, "--Select--")%>  <--error
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.race)%>
```

***CONTROLLER (in NewPersonController)***

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Person person= new Person();
            return View(new PersonFormViewModel(person));   
        }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person person)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) //Also not enter the race parameter
            {
                personRepo.Add(person);
                personRepo.Save();
            }
            return View();  // When return the view I get the error
        }
```

***MODEL (in PersonFormViewModel)***

```
public class PersonFormViewModel
    {


        public Person Person        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public SelectList Races
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string race
        {
            get { return Person.race; }
            set { Person.race = value; }
        }


        public PersonFormViewModel(Person person)
        {

            Person = person;
            RaceRepository repository = new RaceRepository();

            IList<Race> racesList= repository.FindRaces().ToList();
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList =
                from c in racesList
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = c.race,
                    Value = c.id.ToString()
                };

            Races = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");   
        }

    }
```

***IN VALIDATION MODEL***

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Person_Validation))]
public partial class Person    {

}

    public class Person_Validation
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required race")]
        public string race
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Can you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the POST method you have to give the same type of model to the view.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Person person)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                personRepo.Add(person);
                personRepo.Save();
            }
            return View(new PersonFormViewModel(person));
        }
```

Comment: Ok Thank you, I replace the return in [HttPost] by return View(new PersonFormViewModel(person)), but the variable raze is never catched. the race variable still null and never detected by Person_Validation.

Comment: Thanks to Eduardo Campañó and DanielB. First I need to replace in [HttPost]:

    return View() by return View(new PersonFormViewModel(person))


and the problem with never detected by Person_Validation just I need to replace:

    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.race, Model.Races, "--Select--")%> 

by

    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => **model.Person.race**, Model.Races, "--Select--")%> 



Thank you soo much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the ViewModel in the post action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) //Also not enter the race parameter
    {
        personRepo.Add(person);
        personRepo.Save();
    }
    return View(new PersonFormViewModel(person));
}
```

Or maybe

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) //Also not enter the race parameter
    {
        personRepo.Add(person);
        personRepo.Save();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I replace the return in [HttPost] by return View(new PersonFormViewModel(person)), but the the variable raze is never catched. the race variable still null and never detected by Person_Validation.

Comment: Thanks to Eduardo Campañó and DanielB. First I need to replace in [HttPost]:

    return View() by return View(new PersonFormViewModel(person))


and the problem with never detected by Person_Validation just I need to replace:

    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.race, Model.Races, "--Select--")%> 

by

    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => **model.Person.race**, Model.Races, "--Select--")%> 



Thank you soo much!!!